# C++ Why won't my array of text change after I override it with another?

Tags: c++, character-arrays

```
char* Text[16] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N"};
struct Test{
     byte TextID;
} Test;

void TextOverrider(char* Text){
     Test.TextID < 14 ? Test.TextID++ : Test.TextID = 0;
     Text[Test.TextID] = { Text };
}
```

and in my main

```
void main(){
     printf("%s\n\n", Text[0]);
     TextOverrider("Hello");
     TextOverrider("Whats");
     TextOverrider("Up");
     TextOverrider("Dude");
     TextOverrider("Playing");
     TextOverrider("Xbox");
     TextOverrider("Lol");
     TextOverrider("XD");
     TextOverrider("5EVR");
     TextOverrider("Anyonmoose");
     TextOverrider("Hoora");
}
```

I get an error at `Text[Test.TextID] = { Text };` in my text over rider. I'm unsure on how to fix it, I tried everything.

Comment: You want an assignment but you wrote an initialization.

Comment: The paramater named `Text` hides the global variable with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

You've got an array of 16 pointers. That's unusual (In C++ you'd probably want to use `std::string`), but not the direct cause of your problem. You then try voodoo: You pass a function argument *also* named `Text` and expect the compiler to guess which of the two `Text`s you mean. Doesn't work, the argument hides the global. Rename the function argument.

Comment: Of course he gets a compiler error. Since the argument hides the global, the left-hand-side `Text[Test.TextID]` returns the n'th character of the argument, not the n'th global string.

Comment: Or use scope-resolution-operator: `::`

Answer (score 0):

You want an assignment but you wrote an initialization.

Write this instead:

```
void TextOverrider(char* NewText){
 Test.TextID < 14 ? Test.TextID++ : Test.TextID = 0;
 Text[Test.TextID] = NewText;
}
```

*Edit*

Keep in mind that `Text` is an array pointers, that is initialized with the addresses of `char` array literals. The assignment

```
Text[Test.TextID] = NewText;
```

sets a new pointer. You are responsible that the address passed to your function points to an `char` array that will not be changed after the call. You don't copy the string but only the pointer.

Comment: This works :) Thank you. I thought you had to wrap it in brackets because it was an array.

Comment: There are pointers and arrays in question and answer. Could you explain what you want to say with "it"?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of errors.

1. Initialization instead of assignment.

   Write `Text[Test.TextID] = Text;` instead of `Text[Test.TextID] = { Text };`
2. You have a global variable with the same name as the function argument:

   ```
   char* Text[16] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N"};    
   void food(char* Text){
        Text[Test.TextID] = Text;
   }
   ```

   This way, the global variable is invisible and you're trying to assign a `char*` to an element of a `char` array, which is a `char`

   You can also use a global scope operator `::` resulting in `::Text[Test.TextID] = Text;`
3. In `C++` your `main` must be of type `int`, so `void main();` is invalid. You should use `int main();`
4. Usually when you use character literals you want to use `std::string` or at least `const char*`